# Error 10525 during express checkout in PayPal

Tags: yii, paypal-sandbox

I have the following code (using the Yii PHP framework):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$libraryPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.libraries.paypal');
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require_once($libraryPath . '/PPBootStrap.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));

$PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();

$address = new AddressType();
$address->CityName = '';
$address->Name = '';
$address->Street1 = '';
$address->StateOrProvince = '';
$address->PostalCode = '';
$address->Country = '';
$address->Phone = '';

$PaymentDetails->ShipToAddress = $address;

$PaymentDetails->ShippingTotal = $PaymentDetails->HandlingTotal
  = $PaymentDetails->InsuranceTotal = $PaymentDetails->TaxTotal
  = new BasicAmountType('USD', 0);
$PaymentDetails->OrderTotal =  $PaymentDetails->ItemTotal
  = new BasicAmountType('USD', $subscription->price);

$PaymentDetails->PaymentAction = "Sale";

$PaymentDetails->OrderDescription = $subscription->description;

$setECReqDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
$setECReqDetails->PaymentDetails[0] = $PaymentDetails;
$setECReqDetails->CancelURL = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('adListing/listings');
$setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('adReturnFromPaypal');

$setECReqDetails->NoShipping = '0';
$setECReqDetails->AddressOverride = '';
$setECReqDetails->ReqConfirmShipping = '0';

$setECReqType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
$setECReqType->SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = $setECReqDetails;

$setECReq = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
$setECReq->SetExpressCheckoutRequest = $setECReqType;

$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();

$ok = TRUE;
try {
  Yii::trace(__METHOD__ . ': Initiating PayPal API...');
  // wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch
  $setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);

  if($setECResponse && strtoupper($setECResponse->Ack) =='SUCCESS') {
    Yii::trace(__METHOD__ . ': Got successful response from PayPal. Redirecting to it...');
    $token = $setECResponse->Token;
    // Redirect to paypal.com here
    $this->redirect(
      'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . $token);
  }
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
  Yii::trace(__METHOD__ . ': Exception while interacting with PayPal API, error: '
    . $ex->getMessage());
  $ok = FALSE;
}
if (!$ok) {
  Yii::app()->user->setFlash('listings', array(
    'msg'=>'There was an error while interacting with PayPal. Please try again later.',
    'class'=>'flash-error'));
  $this->redirect(array('adListing/listings'));
}
```

The user is redirected to Paypal, but when they login with their sandbox account and try to pay, I get a **10525** error from Paypal:

> This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero.

And the checkout fails. Is there a property that I'm missing to set and the process fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot to include another object needed for the transaction:

```
$itemDetails = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
$itemDetails->Name = $subscription->description;
$itemDetails->Amount = new BasicAmountType('USD', $subscription->price);
$itemDetails->Quantity = 1;
$itemDetails->ItemCategory = 'Digital';

$PaymentDetails->PaymentDetailsItem[0] = $itemDetails;
```

This line

```
$PaymentDetails->ShippingTotal = $PaymentDetails->HandlingTotal
  = $PaymentDetails->InsuranceTotal = $PaymentDetails->TaxTotal
  = new BasicAmountType('USD', 0);
```

should also change to

```
$PaymentDetails->OrderTotal = $PaymentDetails->ItemTotal =
  new BasicAmountType('USD', $subscription->price);
```